Vuforia fails to see a trigger if there is high contrast with the scene around it
I've built an AR app in unity, that is using some targets stuck on posts in outdoor exhibits, so there is a certain distance separating the user from the trigger, and that can't be changed.
In any normal lighting conditions, the triggers work just fine. However if there is a bright sun illuminating the background behind the target (the target is shaded under a tree), it messes up with the pattern recognition, and the target won't trigger the AR
If I lower my hand in view of the camera, even 1/10 of the frame height to cover a bit of the super bright background, the app will automatically recognize the target.
So I think it does have to do with the automated metering of the camera and how that affects the image recognition.
The question is, what can I do to remedy this? Is there a way to mask the camera image input so that it's only revealing the center area to Vuforia? I've no idea how to help the situation.
